# Mongodb schema organization

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, data-modeling

I am new to MongoDB and have a question on schema organization for easy querying.
I am using Python (pymongo) to access the MongoDB database.
I have a prototype JSON file based storage which is loaded into Python dict.

Now, I am looking to migrate it to MongoDB.
I want to use a schema that is most suited for MongoDB queries.

I have two choices:

1. Current JSON file Schema

```
[{name: blah,
 vendor: blah,
 doc1: {
   foo: {
   name: foo,
   alias: some_info,
   id: some_id,
   },
   bar: {
   name: bar,
   alias: some_info_new,
   id: some_id_bar
   },..
 },..
]
```

I have several fields similar to doc1 in which the name fields of the nested documents are extracted out as the key of the nested doc. From what I have read, I think this will make queries on the nested documents within doc1 hard. For eg: If I want to search for matches within doc1 using a given alias, I am not sure how to do that via simple queries. Conceptually , I want a find on `{doc1.*.alias : 'some_info'}`. Perhaps aggregation frameworks might be needed. Searching for nested docs for name key like bar though is still simple via the exists check.

2. Modify the schema to make doc1 and similar fields an array instead

```
[{name: blah
 vendor: blah
 doc1: [

   {
   name: foo,
   alias: some_info,
   id: some_id
   },
   {
   name: bar,
   alias: some_info_new,
   id: some_id_bar
   },..
  ]...
 },..
]
```

Now I can search on alias by specifying find via {'doc1.alias': 'some_info'}

Since there is work involved in moving schemas, I wanted to see if the limitation I see with current schema is valid? In general, I think the second schema treats all fields similarly and would be better. Am I thinking along the right lines?

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The second version has the advantage that you can define indexes and query efficiently on the array fields. Also, if you have a new sub-document with `name : baz`, it is easy to add to the array. Querying and maintaining will also be simpler using array query and update operators.

Comment: Maybe I am not getting it right but what is wrong with iterating the subdocs of doc1 and getting the desired keys ?